# Kivy - get the path to DCIM folder on any android device

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.5

I would like to know exactly how to get the path to the DCIM folder on android using just Kivy.

PyJinus is not an option as it currently doesn't work with Python 3.5

What i tried so far is:

```
DATA_FOLDER = os.getenv('EXTERNAL_STORAGE') if platform is 'android' else os.path.expanduser("~")
```

But this will only get me the user area. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`user_data_dir`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.user_data_dir) and go up if you intend to use the sdcard as a storage for your app (the usage of `user_data_dir` variable creates a folder):

```
from kivy.app import user_data_dir
from os.path import dirname, join
join(dirname(user_data_dir), 'DCIM')
```

or just use its [code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/app.py#L770) directly:

```
DCIM = join('/sdcard', 'DCIM')
```

I think `/sdcard` is only a symlink to the real folder (wherever it is), so a usage of this path just gets the value when accessed e.g. to `/storage/sdcard0` (symlink) or rather directly to the real path.

---

Except those solutions, android has the path in the environment as you've noticed in:

- EXTERNAL_STORAGE (`/storage/emulated/legacy`) again symlink to sdcard
- SECONDARY_STORAGE (`/storage/extSdCard`) i.e. for the external card if you store photos there
- EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET (`/storage/emulated`) basically a parent folder for your sdcard, where the real sdcard (for me) is in `/storage/extSdCard/emulated/0`

Comment: thanks, I wasn't sure what the actual paths are and this helped really much

Comment: @Nick You can always check with `adb shell` (it kind of behaves like bash) or with [Root Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree). The Root Browser should work even without root privileges as a simple file reader (depends on device), which will tell you what paths does your device have. Notice `lrwxrwxrwx` signature for a file, it has even a different icon - that's a symlink.

Answer (score -1):

use this path PATH for where you have to save your file. I would like this way to access android storage.

First, import platform from kivy.utils

```
from kivy.utils import platform
```

Second, use this banch of code to get the path of DCIM

```
    PATH = '.'
    if platform == 'android':
        from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
        request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
        app_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        PATH = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM"
```