# From kivy.app import user_data_dir is not able to import

Tags: python, kivy

I want to get the DCIM folder path in android using kivy.

```
I tried using this code:
from kivy.app import user_data_dir
from os.path import dirname, join
dcim = join(dirname(user_data_dir), 'DCIM')
print(dcim)
```

I got this code from this stack: [Kivy - get the path to DCIM folder on any android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466607/kivy-get-the-path-to-dcim-folder-on-any-android-device)

The error I see:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 /Users/sanjayshreeyansgmail.com/PycharmProjects/Scrach/Furbase.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /Users/sanjayshreeyansgmail.com/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-04-26_30.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/sanjayshreeyansgmail.com/PycharmProjects/Scrach/Furbase.py", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.app import user_data_dir
 ImportError: cannot import name 'user_data_dir' from 'kivy.app' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/app.py)
```

pls help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from os.path import dirname, join
dcim = join(dirname(App().user_data_dir), 'DCIM')
print(dcim)
```

The `user_data_dir` is a property of `App`, so you must have an instance of `App` in order to access it. It is not a class attribute. If your code involves an `App`, use that `App` instance to access `user_data_dir`.